# Can one disambiguate 0 (NULL) for multiple constructors ? and assignment operators?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

In GCC later versions.  How can one (if one can) disambiguate '0' or 'NULL' when one has multiple constructors that take references or pointers ?

ie:

```
class XXX
{
public:
    XXX(const XXX &tocopy);
    XXX(const char *fromAString);
    XXX(const AnotherThing *otherThing);

    operator=(const XXX &tocopy);
    operator=(const char *fromAString);
    operator=(const AnotherThing *otherThing);
};

// nice not to have to cast when setting to NULL for 
// things like smart pointers and strings. Or items that can be initialized from 
// several types of objects and setting to null means "clear"

XXX anXXX = NULL;
anXXX = 0;

// In MSC one can have an 
//    XXX(const int &nullItem) { DEBUG_ASSERT(!nullItem); setnull(); } 
// and the overloads would be disambiguated.  GCC will cause a const int to conflict
// with pointer types.
```

Answer (score 4):

C++ has a *type system*, so variables have types, which are used by the compiler to perform overload resolution:

```
const char * p = 0;
const AnotherThing * q = 0;

XXX a(p), b(q); // uses the respective constructors for the static type of p, q
```

If the overload is ambiguous because you don't use one of the required pointer types, you'll get an error:

```
XXX c(0); // error: ambiguous
```

Comment: Also don't use `const char*` and prefer references to pointers. And probably make those ctors explicit.

Comment: Agreed that one-argument constructors are best declared `explicit`.

Comment: The f(10) call to f(const vector& x) would be kinda neat though =) sry.

Comment: meaning you can't make a variant pointer class that can be set to "NULL" without casting the NULL.  Would be nice to have a "NullType" so one can make an overload that can only have 'const int 0' assigned to it and not conflict with explicit types.  MSC will resolve a const int over pointer and reference types, GCC will not.

Comment: @peterk: I don't see how this would be of any use, though. What would that supposed null-constructor do? Why wouldn't you implement that as a default constructor instead?

Comment: @peterk: It's called `std::nullptr_t`, new in C++11

Comment: @Msalters Nice to have nullptr_t in the queue.

Comment: @Kerrek well it is a tool.  In systems I have made before setting something to null can often mean something different than to a value.  At least in the past where one has things like one element for every pixel on the screen, or variant property fields in an object system it be cleaner and meaningful.  In nay case I was able to make it work right.  Seems GCCs errors are misleading for overloads, but if you have exact matches for all the candiddates it works :)